# Formatting date and background color of a circular plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first time posting an issue for help on this forum so please accept my apologies if I have done anything incorrectly.

I am trying to plot the following data using a circular plot. I had issues with the data completing the circle so I added an additional value for the angle 365 and this is giving me issues when labelling as Month as You will notice "Jan/" in the figure. I would also like to shade the rings of values 10 and 30 with differing shades of grey.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

**Circular Plot**

[image]

**My data set**

```
angle   freq    Month   LH
0   20  Jan a
30  16  Feb a
60  19  Mar a
90  17  Apr a
120 15  May a
150 27  Jun a
180 40  Jul a
210 42  Aug a
240 37  Sep a
270 32  Oct a
310 33  Nov a
330 17  Dec a
365 23.5    a
0   38  Jan b
30  42  Feb b
60  40  Mar b
90  31  Apr b
120 32  May b
150 24  Jun b
180 17  Jul b
210 17  Aug b
240 18  Sep b
270 19  Oct b
310 14  Nov b
330 23  Dec b
365 43.5    b
0   16  Jan c
30  18  Feb c
60  18  Mar c
90  14  Apr c
120 28  May c
150 41  Jun c
180 39  Jul c
210 39  Aug c
240 30  Sep c
270 36  Oct c
310 23  Nov c
330 13  Dec c
365 20.5    c
```

**My Code**

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")

vol <- ggplot(df, aes(x = angle, y = freq, linetype = LH, size = LH, fill = LH)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = -pi/365) +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE, colour = "black") + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "longdash", "dotted")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 1, 1))

vol <- vol + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 
                                180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 365),
                     labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""))
vol <- vol + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 45), breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40))
vol <- vol + annotate("text", x=0, y=12, label="10", size=4, face="bold", family="Arial")
vol <- vol + annotate("text", x=0, y=22, label="20", size=4, face="bold", family="Arial")
vol <- vol + annotate("text", x=0, y=32, label="30", size=4, face="bold", family="Arial")
vol <- vol + annotate("text", x=0, y=42, label="40", size=4, face="bold", family="Arial")

vol <- vol + theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black", size = 1))
vol <- vol + 
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, family = "Tahoma"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "solid", colour = "grey45")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
vol <- vol + xlab("") + ylab("")
vol <- vol + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
vol
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts. I'll try to address them separately:

1. Avoiding the "Jan/" in x-axis label

Don't add 365 / "" as values to breaks / labels in `scale_x_continuous`.

2. Shading rings with different colours at y = 10 / 30

Use `geom_hline` & specify the colour you want for each line. Under polar coordinates, the horizontal lines will wrap around to form rings.

Other minor points that could make your code / chart easier to read:

- Don't include aesthetics that you aren't planning to use. For example, if you want `size = 1` for all the lines, there's no need to specify `size = LH` inside `aes()`.
- Put all the `theme(...)` specifications in one place. It's easier to keep track of them that way. Same for multiple text annotations.
- In a black & white chart, use a lighter shade of grey for the background grid to keep the reader's attention on the actual plot.

Here's an implementation:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = angle, y = freq, linetype = LH)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, colour = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30, colour = "grey55", size = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 10, colour = "grey75", size = 2) +
  annotate("text", 
           x = 0, y = c(12, 22, 32, 42), 
           label = c("10", "20", "30", "40"),
           size = 4) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 11) * 30, labels = month.abb) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 45), breaks = seq(0, 4) * 10) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "longdash", "dotted")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(size = 1, fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightgrey"),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for that @Z.Lin, it was extremely helpful! I made one change, switching out geom_hline for geom_ribbon which allowed for the grey scale to span between the 10 - 20 and 30 - 40 values and made it easier to interpret. Cheers!